# I am facing issue with CircularTimer how to handle it with appium mobile app

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android

[image]

[image]

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"SMS Limits\"))");
    Utils.waitforSeconds(5);
```

[image]

Comment: need to click circular timer through automation

Comment: can you give the element console ?

Comment: enter image description hereenter image description here

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwXE5.png